# What goes first: Sometimes, I bring X (1)'with me' (2)'to Y'?

Tags: word-order

1. Is one of the following constructions incorrect?
2. If not, do they differ semantically in any way, even if only mildly so?

   - *Sometimes, I bring my lunch to work with me.*
   - *Sometimes, I bring my lunch with me to work*

Usually, I prefer fewer words between 'to' and its complement. However, I don't actually know whether, or how, the arrangement of the words affects the meaning of the sentence or whether some people regard some common arrangements as incorrect.

Edit: Although, thinking about it now, 'I bring' entails 'with me'; perhaps I should just write *Sometimes, I bring my lunch to work.*

Thank you.

Comment: I think the 'with me' is redundant in both and should be omitted.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. I cut it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you give, both phrases *to work* and *with me* are adverbial phrases modifying the verb *bring*. In this example, changing the word order does not create ambiguity, because neither phrase is likely to be misconstrued to refer to some other part of the sentence.

Comment: Yes; contrast: _Tomorrow, I'm going to ask Danny to come to work with me_ / _Tomorrow, I'm going to ask Danny to come with me to work_. The latter, I'd say, will more probably be interpreted as _Tomorrow, I'm going to ask Danny to come with me to do some work_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Excellent point. But interestingly, the ambiguity is partly derived from the shift of *to work* from a preposition/noun phrase to an infinitive.